# How does this C struct pointer casting to other struct works?

Tags: c

```
#define MACHINE_GET_CLASS(obj) \
    OBJECT_GET_CLASS(MachineClass, (obj), TYPE_MACHINE)
#define OBJECT_GET_CLASS(class,obj,name) OBJECT_CLASS_CHECK(class, object_get_class(OBJECT(obj)), name)
#define OBJECT_GET_CLASS(class, obj, name) \
    OBJECT_CLASS_CHECK(class, object_get_class(OBJECT(obj)), name)
#define OBJECT(obj) ((Object *)(obj))
struct MachineState {
    /*< private >*/
    Object parent_obj;
    Notifier sysbus_notifier;
    //...
}
struct Object
{
    /*< private >*/
    ObjectClass *class;
    ObjectFree *free;
    GHashTable *properties;
    uint32_t ref;
    Object *parent;
};

MachineState *machine;
MachineClass *machine_class = MACHINE_GET_CLASS(machine);
```

By following the macros,

```
MACHINE_GET_CLASS(machine) = OBJECT_GET_CLASS(MachineClass, (machine), TYPE_MACHINE) =  
OBJECT_CLASS_CHECK(MachineClass, object_get_class(OBJECT(machine)), TYPE_MACHINE)
```

See that `OBJECT(machine) = ((Object *)(machine))`

How can we cast the struct pointer `MachineState*` to `Object *`?

I think I'm missing something here, I'm much more familiar with C++. Also, what does an extra parenthesis mean around the object? Like in `(machine)` at `OBJECT_GET_CLASS(MachineClass, (machine), TYPE_MACHINE)`

Comment: The extra parentheses ensure that the argument to the macro is not misinterpreted.  It matters when you have an expression in the macro (so `#define M(m) ((m) * 3)` will work differently from `#define M(m) (m * 3)` if you invoke `M(3 + 9)`).  That's the easy bit.

Comment: Where is `OBJECT_CLASS_CHECK` defined?

Comment: What is the definition of `MachineClass`? `Object`? `ObjectClass`? `object_get_class`?

Comment: The code is missing too many relevant parts for the question to be answerable. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding this is only legal and works because the first member of `struct MachineState` is of type `struct Object` and when casting the compiler will just give you a pointer by which you can access the size of `struct Object` from the given address - whatever address type you provided.

So this technique should be used very carefully because it can easily result in undefined behavior.

Consider the following:

```
struct structA {
    int i;
    char c;
};

struct structB {
    struct structA sA;
    int i;
};

struct structC {
    int i;
};

int main() { 

    struct structA A = { 42, 'a' };
    struct structB B = { {43, 'b'}, 44 };
    struct structC C = { 45 };

    struct structA *pA1 = (struct structA*)&B;
    struct structA *pA2 = (struct structA*)&C;

    printf ("pA1: %d %c\n", pA1->i, pA1->c);
    printf ("pA2: %d %c\n", pA2->i, pA2->c);

    return 0;
}
```

So when casting `(struct structA*)&B` I get the expected result because the pointer type exactly matches the member at the beginning of `struct structB`  but when casting `(struct structA*)&C` I will access undefined memory section.

Comment: I was going to post the same answer, but `machine` in the question is actually of type `MachineClass`, which we know nothing about.

Comment: @Lundin `MachineState *machine` and `MachineClass *machine_class`

Comment: But no struct definition of `MachineClass`.